TypeScript brainteaser: returning an overloaded function
In TypeScript, I can easily create a function with overloads that returns a different return type depending on the input. E.g.,:
function doSomething(mode: "ReturnPromise"): Promise<any>;
function doSomething(mode: "FireAndForget"): void;
function doSomething(mode: "ReturnPromise" | "FireAndForget"): Promise<any> | void {
  if (mode == "ReturnPromise") {
    console.log("Will return a promise")
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    console.log("Can quit as-is")
    return;
  }
}

doSomething("FireAndForget");
// Logs "Can quit as-is"

doSomething("ReturnPromise")
  .then(() => console.log("done"))
// Logs "Will return a Promise" followed by "done"

But suppose I want to have a function that generates such a function. For example:
function generateDoer(logger: (message: string) => void):
  ((mode: "ReturnPromise") => Promise<any>)
  | ((mode: "FireAndForget") => void) {
  return (mode: "ReturnPromise" | "FireAndForget") => {
    if (mode == "ReturnPromise") {
      logger("Will return a promise")
      return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
      logger("Can quit as-is")
      return;
    }
  }
}

Conceptually, and at runtime, the function works the same as before:
const doer = generateDoer((message) => console.log(message));

doer("FireAndForget");
// Logs "Can quit as-is"

doer("ReturnPromise")
  .then(() => console.log("done"))
// Logs "Will return a Promise" followed by "done"

BUT, from the TypeScript compiler perspective, the calls above are deeply unhappy. TypeScript tells me that I can't even pass FireAndForget as the first argument:

And likewise, it doesn't think that I can call .then on the Promise-returning one:

Any ideas on how to convince it to work after all? Thank you very much!
TypeScript Playground link here.

P.S.: Updated from a day later: jsejcksn's solution worked for me perfectly. For posterity & ease of reference: here is a diff showing the code changes required between my original problem, and the described solution:


Here's an example demonstrating returning an overloaded closure as shown in the code in your question (including the return type annotation). Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write an answer based on it (or find a duplicate target for this question). If not, what did I miss?

@jsejcksn, that is absolutely brilliant, thank you so much! I've never seen syntax quite like this, nor could I have stumbled on it by mere permutation :-). I really appreciate it!
If you want to write a full answer, I will gladly accept it as the perfect solution

@jsejcksn, here is a diff that helps illustrate the delta between the original and your solution, feel free to re-use in your answer: image

Inside the higher-order function body: you can declare the overloaded closure using idiomatic overload and implementation signatures:
function generateDoer(logger: (message: string) => void) {
  // overload signatures:
  function doer(mode: "ReturnPromise"): Promise<void>;
  function doer(mode: "FireAndForget"): void;
  // implementation signature:
  function doer(mode: "ReturnPromise" | "FireAndForget") {
    if (mode == "ReturnPromise") {
      logger("Will return a promise");
      return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
      logger("Can quit as-is");
      return;
    }
  }
  // return the closure:
  return doer;
}

…and to describe these overload signatures in an explicit return type annotation, you can simply copy them as call signatures inside braces:
type Doer = {
  (mode: "ReturnPromise"): Promise<void>;
  (mode: "FireAndForget"): void;
};

function generateDoer(logger: (message: string) => void): Doer {
  // …implementation from above
}


You might not encounter this syntax often, but it might help to think of the call signatures as resembling methods without property names — they're intrinsic to the type itself.


It's not necessary to define the return type annotation as a named alias — you can write it inline. All together that looks like this:
TS Playground
function generateDoer(logger: (message: string) => void): {
  (mode: "ReturnPromise"): Promise<void>;
  (mode: "FireAndForget"): void;
} {
  function doer(mode: "ReturnPromise"): Promise<void>;
  function doer(mode: "FireAndForget"): void;
  function doer(mode: "ReturnPromise" | "FireAndForget") {
    if (mode == "ReturnPromise") {
      logger("Will return a promise");
      return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
      logger("Can quit as-is");
      return;
    }
  }
  return doer;
}


Wonderful, it works perfectly, even when I introduce other complications in my actual use-case (generics , etc). Thank you for the detailed explanation!
